# Смена картинок по таймеру в программе на java(swing)

Tags: java, swing

цель: есть графический интерфейс реализованный с помощью swing, добавлена картинка, хочу чтобы картинка сменялась на другую в зависимости от времени суток по таймеру. Может кто-нибудь что подсказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. Получите текущее время. Для работы с временем и датой можно использовать класс `java.util.Date`. Как получить текущую дату и время, например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345545/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-int-%D0%B2-android);
2. С помощью `if`'ов проверьте, какое сейчас время суток. (например: время больше 22:00 но меньше 7:00 - ночь, больше 7:00, но меньше 10:00 - утро и так далее, надо только решить, когда начинается и заканчивается утро `=)` )
3. В зависимости от времени суток (которое уже определено) отображаете нужную картинку;

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали: 1)время текущее выставил,2) картинку добавил в if по времени суток, создал окно графическое, туда добавил картинку, картинка появляется в окне, только после того как изменяю размер окна дёрнув за край, а так при компиляции просто пустое графическое окно!

Comment: @BreezyDay это известная проблема. [Посмотрите это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814781/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-jbutton-%D0%B2-jframe-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java-swing)